# How to publish AIML embedded with javascript?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, aiml

I've written an AIML file for a chat bot and I'd like to build an interactive web application which allows me to chat with the bot in the web browser.

Is it possible to achieve this with HTML & Javascript?

Comment: Do you want to publish the AIML source code or to make your chatbot work in the browser?

Comment: Yeah, do you have any solution about this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no short answer on how to write a web application which allows a user to interact with your AIML. Writing such an application from scratch will be much more work then compiling the AIML was.

The easiest option would be to use a pre-built service like PandoraBots which allows you to upload AIML files and interact with them in the web browser. It's free to use the [explorer part of website](https://playground.pandorabots.com/en/bot/). They also have paid developer options which generates an API to bridge your AIML script and any applications you might want to build. It can be easily connected to work with common chat apps like Google talk ect.

If you decide to build everything from scratch you might want to check out the [AIML Interpreter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aimlinterpreter) library for nodejs.

UPDATE: Here is a node.js based interpreter that you might find useful https://github.com/mrchimp/surly2

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at AIML too and had similar questions. I just found RiveScript [RiveScript](https://www.rivescript.com) and it looks like it fits your need to run javascript based on a match. It is not AIML, but very close.  There is also at least [one tool](https://github.com/aichaos/aiml2rs) to convert from AIML to RiveScript, so I would say this fits your needs within those constraints.